# mySQL return different values based on entry existence

Tags: mysql

I'm executing a large query using a derived table called "DT" which relates some people with a particular score. I also have a regular table "persons" which contains all relevant people and a "name" field (among others).

I need to select person, score for all people returning their score from the DT table if such an entry exits or 0 otherwise.

For example...

If persons contains:
alice
bob
carl

And DT contains:
bob 100
carl 90

I need to return:
alice 0
bob 100
carl 90

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select p.name, ifnull(d.score, 0) as score
from persons p
left outer join DT d on p.name = d.name
```